# How to write this code using join, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

```
SELECT departments.department_name, result1.total_amt 
FROM departments,  
( SELECT employees.department_id, SUM(employees.salary) total_amt  
FROM employees  
GROUP BY department_id) result1 
WHERE result1.department_id = departments.department_id;
```

Comment: Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ... you can get tour in site and ask question better than this... for give positive feedback

Answer (score 0):

You can use the both tables in a single query as follows:

```
SELECT departments.department_name,
       SUM(employees.salary) total_amt 
FROM departments
JOIN employees ON employees.department_id = departments.department_id  
GROUP BY departments.department_id, departments.department_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code -

SELECT dept.department_name, SUM(emp.salary)
FROM departments dept inner join employees emp on dept.department_id =dept.department_id
GROUP BY dept.department_name;